# Sphinx autodoc including classes and methods

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I have python classes and some of them are in their own files

i.e. userdata.py:

```
class userdata:
    """User input class for reading..."""

    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname        


    def trykey(self,name,injson):
....
```

I have tried multiple methods to be able to refer to a specific method in that class in the documentation, but it did not work.

I am generating autodoc via command

```
sphinx-apidoc
```

It only generates modules for the code above

```
_lib.io package
=====================

Submodules
----------

.. toctree::

   lib.io.userdata

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: lib.io
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Similar problem for modules with multiple classes 
i.e. ad1.py

```
class inner1(inherited)
....
class inner2(inherited)
....def
....
```

autodoc:

```
_lib.ad.ad1 module
===========================================

.. automodule:: lib.ad.ad1
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Is there a way to get autoclass and automethod automatically generated  as well.

Comment: Note that sphinx-apidoc only generates `automodule` directives. If you want to use `autoclass` or `autofunction`, you have to add these directives by hand. In order to understand exactly what your problem is, we need more details (preferably in the form of a [mcve]).

Comment: ok then the answer is no as far as i understand. thank you

Comment: You don't *have* to use `autoclass` or `automethod`. Using only `automodule` should work.

Comment: @mzjn Do you say it is possible to use `automodule` only, to show the class docstrings of every class within a module? And the same for the functions defined in the module?

Comment: @Ecuashungo: Yes, that is what I mean. But there are cases when `autoclass` or `autofunction` are needed.

Comment: @mzjn Interesting! I haven't figured out how to do that yet. Do I have to use a specific option below `.. automodule:: module_name`? Or how would that be done?

Comment: @Ecuashungo You should add the `:members:` option. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autodoc.html?highlight=autodoc#directive-automodule

Comment: I tried to follow this thread but I still don't understand how to automatically document all classes without explicitly specifying them in the `index.rst` file with the `autoclass` directive. I tried without but that gives no class documentation at all. And the Sphinx documentation says autodoc is only semi-automatic. So it seems to me @mzjn is wrong about that it "should work".

Comment: @ChristianBrolin: To document all members in a module, use `automodule`. To document all classes in a module using `autoclass`, you need one `autoclass` directive per class.